# Why does my screenshot look terrible when previewed in Windows Photo Viewer?

Tags: images, screenshot, windows-photo-viewer

I recently came across an issue that turned out to be much simpler than it was, and I thought I'd document it here. Maybe everyone but me is aware of how Photo Viewer works, but just in case, I thought it would be worth documenting.

I was working on a current programming project, which of course consisted largely of text. I needed to take a screenshot of the code for Facebook, so I used the <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd> button to capture the screen, and then copied it into Photoshop and saved it. When I previewed the saved screenshot in Windows Photo Viewer, I was frustrated that the text was quite badly blurred, to the point that it wouldn't be suitable for uploading for professional purposes anywhere. I chalked the apparent "loss" of quality down to Photoshop's compression of bitmap images, and spent the next hour or so figuring out what combination of file format and settings I needed to save the screenshot into to get it to look exactly as it did in Photoshop.

Obviously, it turned out my problem didn't involve Photoshop or a "loss" of any quality at all, but the program that Windows was using to preview the file - a basic program I've used so many times I can't count, and yet which I evidently still didn't fully understand the workings of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I finally turned my attention to Windows Photo Viewer, I noticed a button I've never paid much attention to - come to think of it, I'd never paid much attention to any of the controls in Photo Viewer. It'd become such a natural extension of the way I use Windows I'd forgotten I used it at all.

The button I noticed was the `Actual Size` button, located just to the right of the Zoom button - or the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

From Photo Viewer's own Help documentation:

> To view the picture at its actual size, click "Actual size". To make the entire picture fit in the Windows
>   Photo Viewer window, click "Fit to window".

It turns out that Windows Photo Viewer defaults to displaying an image fully zoomed out. This is fine and expected for most images - images small enough to fit in the application's viewport - but for bigger images like screenshots, it also means you're not seeing the image at its actual size, because *Photo Viewer prioritises seeing all of the image at once rather than as much of the image as possible at best quality*. It turns out when I thought I was seeing a loss of quality in my newly-saved screenshot, I was actually just seeing a slightly-zoomed out version of the image. Clicking the `Actual Size` button, of course, adjusted the Zoom to the level it needed to to show me my screenshot as it actually looks, which was just as I expected it to.

*Like I said initially, it's possible this won't be of use to anyone else because I'm the only one that doesn't know how Photo Viewer works. In any case, I thought it was worth documenting on here; if nothing else, to help others also prone to suffering from brain farts. :-)*